# Broadcast Channel API communication is not working inside servicenow iframe and child window opened from iframe with same origin in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, crm, servicenow, broadcast-channel

We have created a web application  with 2 pages broadcast.html and receiver.html. Broadcast.html is added as iframe in servicenow crm using openframe widget and receiver.html is opened seperately  from broadcast.html. We tried to make communication between 2 pages using broadcast api and its not working in chrome browser when open inside servicenow but the communication is working if broadcast.html is not loaded in servicenow.

Codes are attached below

Openframe widget code

```
<html> 
<body style="padding-top: 0rem;">
<iframe id="softphone" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; border: none;" allow="microphone *" src="https://localhost:9981/broadcast.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

Broadcast HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <!-- The title will change to greet the user -->
  <h1 id="title">Hey</h1>
  <input id="name-field" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/>
  
</body>
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
        window.open("/reciever.html?ts=" + new Date().getTime(), "reciever", "fullscreen=no, width=455, height=320, resizable=no, location=no'");
        //window.open("reciever.html");
    }

var bc = new BroadcastChannel('test_channel');

(()=>{
  const title = document.getElementById('title');
  const nameField = document.getElementById('name-field');
  const setTitle = (userName) => {
    title.innerHTML = 'Hey ' + userName;
  }

  

  // When the page loads check if the title is in our localStorage
  if (localStorage.getItem('title')) {
    setTitle(localStorage.getItem('title'));
  } else {
    setTitle('please tell us your name');
  }

  nameField.onchange = (e) => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    // In the localStorage we set title to the user's input
    localStorage.setItem('title', inputValue);
    // Update the title on the current page 
    setTitle(inputValue);
    // Tell the other pages to update the title
    bc.postMessage(inputValue);
  }
})()
</script>
</html>
```

Receiver HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <!-- The title will change to greet the user -->
  <h1 id="title">Hey</h1>

  </body>
  <script>
    var bc = new BroadcastChannel('test_channel');

    bc.onmessage = (messageEvent) => {
        console.log(messageEvent.data);
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML=messageEvent.data;
  
  }
  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: We have another product entirely, but we are now suddenly observing this same issue. Seems to happen only with Chrome. In our tests it is working fine with Edge and Firefox.

In Chrome it seems BroadcastChannel is just silently failing to deliver messages. There are no warnings, errors, nothing we can observe using regular developer toolbar.

But weirdly, it's not happening for all users. Some users on Chrome are not experiencing the issue. We are attempting to gather working/non-working Chrome version details.

Comment: Suggestion: Remove "servicenow" from title